# Prevent Apache from showing first virtual host if domain does not exist?

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm

Not sure when but WHM/cPanel and/or Apache have changed how they handle requests for domains that do not exist.

Previously it would redirect to http://requested-domain.tld/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi however it will now simply show the content of the first domain listed in the virtual hosts without changing the domain.

I've tried adding variations of the following to:

- `/etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_virtualhost_2.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/conf.d/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName subdomain.server-domain.tld
  RedirectPermanent / /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
  #RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  #RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  #RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi [L,R=302]
</VirtualHost>
```

Neither redirect the request to http://requested-domain.tld/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to `/etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/pre_virtualhost_global.conf` resolved the issue:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443>
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <IfModule suphp_module>
        suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
    </IfModule>
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <IfModule ssl_module>
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/cpanel/cpanel.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/cpanel/ssl/cpanel/cpanel.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /var/cpanel/ssl/cpanel/cpanel.pem
        SSLUseStapling Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule security2_module>
        SecRuleEngine On
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

For servers with multiple IP addresses, you are required to replicate for each IP.

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360061002473-How-do-I-set-a-default-VirtualHost-for-each-IP-address-